# Qual a diferença ao criar um projeto class libray (.net framework) e class library(.net standard) no VS2017?

Tags: c#, .net, template, class-library, .net-standard

Quais as diferenças e usos desses tipos de projetos?

[image: Templates do Visual Studio]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Imagina que você queira que sua aplicação tenha portabilidade para criação de quaisquer tipos de API's, como .NET Framework, .NET Core, Xamarin e etc. Neste caso você utilizaria o .NET Standard, porém seus recursos seriam bem limitados, afinal, você teria acesso somente a API's que seriam compatíveis para todas as plataformas.

Já o .NET Framework, você teria acesso a todas as API's do .NET Framework, porém você só poderia criar aplicações para plataformas que suportem o .NET Framework.

Caso tenha mais dúvidas, de uma olhada [neste link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/) da Microsoft que explica quando utilizar ou não o .NET Standard.

Espero ter ajudado.

Abraço!

**UPDATE 1**

Achei [este post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/) bastante interessante sobre o assunto e em português pra ficar mais claro.

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou sim!!

Answer (score 5):

Se escolher o .NET Standard só poderá usar os recursos listados nessa especificação. Qualquer coisa que não esteja nele gerará um erro. Note que ele só tem a lista de componentes, não tem os códigos mesmo, os códigos ele pega de outro lugar. Não existe de forma concreta um .NET Standard, é abstrato para você se garantir que só usurá coisas que funciona em todo .NET compatível com o Standard.

Se escolher o .NET Framework poderá usar o que está dentro dele e aí só poderá usa biblioteca em projetos para o .NET Framework. Não poderá no .NET Core, no Xamarin, no Mono, etc.