# Problemas ao referenciar uma classlibrary do .net framework core - C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Preciso referenciar uma *class library* do .NET Core na minha camada WPF que é uma camada do .NET Framework.

Porém estoura um erro de compilação dizendo que não é possível referenciá-la.

A mensagem do erro é:

> O projeto "NomeDoProjeto.csproj" tem como destino 'netcoreapp2.0'. Ele não pode ser referenciado por um projeto que tem como destino 'NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'

Como faço para resolver esse problema?

Comment: Por favor, coloque o erro em texto, não imagem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não faz. Os dois frameworks são coisas diferentes e **incompatíveis**.

Pra isto existe o .NET Standard, você pode fazer com que a *class library* tenha como *target* o .NET Standard e isso vai fazer com que ela possa ser usada tanto em projetos .NET Core como em projetos .NET Framework.

Você pode ver mais na [documentação do .NET Standard](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/net-standard).

Esta pergunta também pode te ajudar: [Qual a diferença ao criar um projeto class libray (.net framework) e class library(.net standard) no VS2017?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/253489/18246)