# Qual tipo de biblioteca do .NET devo escolher em projeto C#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, library

Estou pensando  em criar  um novo  projeto em c# vi três tipos de bibliotecas que  me chamaram a atenção e não consegui distinguir exatamente qual seria a melhor aplicabilidade em  cada projeto.

- .NET Framework Class Library
- .NET Core Class Library
- Standard Class Library

Claramente pude compreender  que elas  são  especificas se o  projeto vai *cross-plataform* ou se é nativo  do Windows entre outros.

Mas  um  exemplo me deixou  intrigado: .NET Core é *cross-plataform* podendo  ser utilizada por exemplo em servidores Linux, e o Standard é utilizado também no mesmo  contexto.

Comment: Bibliotecas .NET Framework é para .NET Framework. Bibliotecas .NET Core é para .NET Core. Bibliotecas .NET Standard é para ambos. Uma tende a ser mais limitada que a outra, veja a resposta do Maniero para mais detalhes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Para projetos novos só deve usar [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101) que será o único que *framework* que irá sobreviver ([ver mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/225927/101)). Veja mais em [O .NET Framework está morto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101). [Não sei se tem relevância ainda, mas...](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156517/101)

O .NET Standard não é uma biblioteca, então você não pode usar. Como o próprio nome diz é um padrão, é uma [especificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101). Pode ver mais em [Qual a diferença ao criar um projeto class libray (.net framework) e class library(.net standard) no VS2017?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/253489/101). Você escolhe ele quando quer garantir que o projeto atenda a essa especificação e não permita nada fora dela que é de uma implementação específica da [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/230192/101).

Se ainda estiver usando um projeto antigo que foi criado com o .NET Framework então deve usar o primeiro.

Veja mais sobre [Quais as diferenças dos ".NET"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/275588/101). E [O que devo entender quando dizem ".NET"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184716/101). Entenda as [versões do .NET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21672/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).